# Set session not to expire automatically

Tags: python, caching, cherrypy

I am working on store data into cache memory using cherrypy. I am using below code to put data into cache :

```
import cherrypy
import datetime
import sys
from cherrypy.lib.caching import MemoryCache
cache = MemoryCache()

def putDataIntoCache(self, *args, **kwargs):
    data = cache.get()
    if not data:
        obj = kwargs
        size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
        cache.put(obj, size)
        data = obj
return 'obj: %s, id: %s' % (cache.get(), id(cache.get()))
```

But problem is that cache data is clear automatically after 10 second. 
I found that `delay = 600`  set in cache.py class. For this reason data is cleared after 10 second.

I just want to clear cache data when cherrypy server restarted.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you referring to the `cherrypy/lib/caching.py` module? How are you building the `cache` object that you are using on your sample?

Comment: @cyraxjoe Yes I am using caching.py module

Comment: How are you using It? Directly as a tool?  Can you show me the statement on which you create the cache object.

Comment: @cyraxjoe Please check my update question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you shouldn't be using the cache directly. Specially when you don't really want to have the benefit of finer control of the cache invalidation.

You can do something like this:

```
import cherrypy as cp                                                                                                                                                           
from cherrypy.process.plugins import SimplePlugin                                                                                                                               

class CachePlugin(SimplePlugin):                                                                                                                                                      

    def start(self):                                                                                                                                                            
        self.bus.log('Initializing cache')                                                                                                                                      
        cp.cache = {}                                                                                                                                                           

    def stop(self):                                                                                                                                                             
        self.bus.log('Clearing cache')                                                                                                                                          
        cp.cache = {}                                                                                                                                                           

class Root:                                                                                                                                                                     

    @cp.expose                                                                                                                                                                  
    def default(self, user=None):                                                                                                                                               
        if user is not None:                                                                                                                                                    
            cp.cache['user'] = user                                                                                                                                             
        return cp.cache.get('user', 'No user')                                                                                                                                  


CachePlugin(cp.engine).subscribe()                                                                                                                                                    
cp.quickstart(Root())
```

Try it with: `/`, `/?user=test`, `/` and `/?user=new_user`

You could contain the cache on the plugin and publish the channels to modify it but in general the idea is that you don't really need the cache tool, just to listen when the server starts and stops (I'm assuming you are using the autoreloader).

This is simply a dictionary monkey patched on the cherrypy module. This is quick and simple. It's pretty late here in Mexico... I hope this helps.

More info about the plugins: http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extend.html#server-wide-functions

Comment: I got exception from here "cp.cache['user'] = user " Undefined variable from import: cache

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty  How are you deploying the application? With the CP server itself? Does the phrase "Initializing cache" appears on the beginning of the log?

Comment: Right now I am using python in eclipse. When I used the above code in eclipse then I got the exception but strange thing is that program is running with exception.